# How to ask user permission for receiving notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am using Swift 3.0 and I want the user to be able to click on a button to trigger the alert box that requests his permission for using notifications.

I am surprised not to find more information about that.

I would like to support iOS 9.0 as well as 10.

What is the way to trigger this ask-for-permission alert box again ?

Answer (score 12):

```
import UserNotifications
```

and Declare this **UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate** Method in header

in appDelegates just put this code :

```
func registerForRemoteNotification() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
```

And when user give permission at that time you can get user token via **`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`** Delegates method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        print(token)

        print(deviceToken.description)
        if let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString {
            print(uuid)
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "ApplicationIdentifier")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


    }
```

Comment: I bound this function "registerForRemoteNotification()" on a button but nothing happens, is this normal ? (I use simulator)

Comment: its working fine just call that method when you want to ask for permission and ya dont forgot to call delegates method of didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and import import UserNotifications for register

Comment: In my case user already denied the pop up once... maybe that's the reason why I cannot make it pop up again with your code ?

Comment: @lapin just reinstall your app that means remove app from your device and re install it . so its pop up for ask permission.

Answer (score 10):

Below is the full code for all the scenarios, check with break points

Working copy of code, copy paste in your Appdelegate.
**XCode 9 , iOS 11, Swift 4**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  PushNotification

import UIKit
import UserNotifications
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if #available(iOS 10, *)
        { // iOS 10 support
            //create the notificationCenter
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            // set the type as sound or badge
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound,.alert,.badge]) { (granted, error) in
                if granted {
                    print("Notification Enable Successfully")
                }else{
                    print("Some Error Occure")
                }
            }
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
        else if #available(iOS 9, *)
        {
            // iOS 9 support
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
        else if #available(iOS 8, *)
        {
            // iOS 8 support
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound,
                                                                                                     .alert], categories: nil))
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
        else
        { // iOS 7 support
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.badge, .sound, .alert])
        }
        return true
    }


    //get device token here
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
        deviceToken: Data)
    {
        var token = ""
        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
            token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
        }
        print("Registration succeeded!")
        print("Token: ", token)

        //send tokens to backend server
//        storeTokens(token)


    }

    //get error here
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error:
        Error) {
        print("Registration failed!")
    }

    //get Notification Here below ios 10
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        // Print notification payload data
        print("Push notification received: \(data)")


    }

    //This is the two delegate method to get the notification in iOS 10..
    //First for foreground
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        print("Handle push from foreground")
        // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
        print("\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    }
    //Second for background and close
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response:UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        print("Handle push from background or closed")
        // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you will know if this is from closed or background
        print("\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    }



    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use UserNotifications framework to handle notifications for iOS app. Once you ask for authorization system will automatically prompts alert to user.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (success, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Request Authorization Failed (\(error), \(error.localizedDescription))")
            }
            else{
               //Success.. do something on success
            }
        }
```

For iOS 9.0 :

```
private func requestAuthorizationForiOS9AndBelow(){
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
        types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings) 
}
```

Comment: This won't work for iOS 9 as `UNUserNotificationCenter` was only introduced in iOS 10

Comment: You can use UIUserNotificationSettings for iOS 9.0

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

In `AppDelegate` inside the `didFinishLaunching` method

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: { (granted, error) in

            if (granted == true){

            }else{
                print("request authorisation error: \(error)")
            }

        })

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```